# Javadoc text not appearing on mouse hover

Tags: mouseover, eclipse-juno

Recently at work we've been told to switch to using the Spring Tool Suite (running Eclipse-Juno platform SR2 v3.8.2)

Things are mostly well and good except when I go to mouse over any methods or constructors, my javac window only appears blank.  (see screenshot)

I've looked through the preferences (predominately Content Assist and Hovers), but nothing seems to address this.

Any ideas?  Note: I still have Eclipse Luna on my laptop too...mainly because I got fed up with trying to remedy the issue and would go back to using that instead.  Could that be the culprit?

[image: Mouse is currently hovered over "println"]

Answer (score 1):

Check hover configuration in Eclipse, `Window - Preferences; select Java -> Editor -> Hovers`

[Using Hover Help](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_hover_help.htm)

Comment: this is what I've looked at and it's still not working properly